# How would I make my page choose between getting data from a drop-down menu or a text-field?

Tags: python, html

thanks to some help from yesterday from stackoverflow, I've made progress in my code. But I have a question, concerning my page. Here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print 'Content-type: text/html\n'
print

#May 17
import cgi, cgitb
cgitb.enable()

form=cgi.FieldStorage()

#May19
dataset1=open('Book1.csv','r')
dataset2=open('Race Demographic by state.txt','r')

sources='''<hr><h4>Sources!</h4><a     href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_the_United_States">Race Demographics</a>
<a href="http://voices.yahoo.com/average-sat-scores-state-2010-7702520.html?cat=4">SAT     Scores</a>
<a href="http://lisa.stuy.edu/~keiran.carpen/BriansDirectory/Sat scores by     state.txt">SAT Scores txt file</a>
<a href="http://lisa.stuy.edu/~keiran.carpen/BriansDirectory/Race Demographic by     state.txt">Race Demographics txt file</a></body></html>'''

def datasplitter(x):
    data = x.read()
    return data.split("\n")


def datdatamang(x):
    data = datasplitter(x)
    index = 0
    WhileNumber = 0
    while index < len(data):
        WhileNumber = 0
        string = data[index]
        string.split(" ")
        x=''
        while WhileNumber < len(string):
            if string[WhileNumber] == ',':
                x=x+'</td><td>'
            else:
                x=x+string[WhileNumber]
            WhileNumber+= 1
        ' '.join(string)
        data[index]='<tr><td>'+x+'</td></tr>'
        index+=1
    result=' '.join(data)
    result='''<table border='1'>'''+result+'</table>'
    return result

#May 19
def getDescription():
    page = ''
    state = ''
#May20
    if 'Drop' in form:
        if form['Drop'].value =="Description":
            page+= 'Ever since its conception, the SAT examinations have been widely     controversial.Many individuals believe that their race is the most intellectually superior,     and that their SAT scores reflect on their superiority. It is my job to find this     correlation between scores and race and end the battle among the races!'
        if form['Drop'].value=="High SAT Scores":
            page+= datdatamang(dataset1)
        if form['Drop'].value=="Race Demographics":
            page+= datdatamang(dataset2)
        if form['Drop'].value=="source":
            page+= sources
        else: 
    return page

#May 21
def getState():
    table=''
    if 'on' in form:
        state+= form['on'].value
    if state in dataset1:
        state.header=dataset1.index(state)
        for n in dataset1[state.header]:
            table+='''<tr>'''+n+'''</tr>'''
        return '''<td>'''+table+'''</td>'''


def getRacebyState():
    if 'on' in form:
        state+= form['on'].value
    if state in dataset2:
        state.header=dataset2.index(state)
        for n in dataset2[state.header]:
            table+='''<tr>'''+n+'''</tr>'''
        return '''<td>'''+table+'''</td>'''




#May 20
print '''<html><title>SAT Analysis</title>'''
print '''<body>'''
print getDescription()
print '''</body></html>'''



#May 17 - Writing the analysisV2.html file and starting the code
#May 19 - Tables, and the like
#May 20 - Writing if statements for drop-down menu, building the page.
#May 21 - Working on text fields and getState
```

Essentially, my page works so that you have a drop-down menu to choose from (choosing one of these values: e.g. "High SAT Scores" and "Race Demographics" causes my python code to generate a page that with tables, or descriptions concerning the drop-down menu option), or a text field (which searches for a state in my CSV files, and returns a table-row with the data about that particular State). Using cgi.FieldStorage() Python collects the value that is submitted through the HTML form. However, how do I write the code so that I only send a value from the text-field only, through the HTML form.

I.e. if I do not want to use the drop-down menu, and instead only want to use the text-field to find a state in particular and not submit form data through the drop-down menu, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether I am missing something here but, assuming 'on' is the name of your text field, you can check to see whether the text field is empty like so:

```
if 'on' in form and form['on']:
    doSomethingWithOn()
else:
    doSomethingWithDrop()
```

Comment: Yep, 'on' is the name of my text field. And 'Drop' is the name of my drop-down menu. Do I place this code before my block of code containing getDescription, getState and getRaceByState? Or do I place it at the end of my code-block, so that it chooses which page to generate?

Comment: You can do either, your functions (everything starting with def) do not get executed until you call them like you do in `print getDescription()`. So it is up to you how you want to structure your code. The important take-away is that you can check whether a form field is empty by doing `if form['myFormElementName']:`

Comment: Was my answer what you were looking for? If so, please mark as accepted or otherwise clarify the question